# Copy Column B Row where Data in Column A is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Below is the sample data:

```
 Column A     Column B
    123           abc
    456           def
    789           ghi
```

What I need to do is to find `456` in Column `A` and then Copy the adjacent cell value `DEF` to another cell.

What is the best way to do this?

Preferably VBA code that can Paste data in a Cell itself.

Comment: Do the sample data have 456 in another Rows also or is only once !!

Comment: @RajeshS each value in column A only is their once

Comment: Then better use `Vlookup`.

Answer (score 0):

If the resultant value is always fixed to "the adjacent cell [in column B]", then I would suggest using an `OFFSET MATCH` combination.  If you provide more details on your exact usage requirements, we can help you build the formula with more specificity; or, you can refer to [this example](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-offset-match-match/) for your reference.  There are other methods as well, but I believe this would be most simple and doesn't require VBA.